# jquery with asp.net select item change event

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have number of dropdownlist controls.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlusertype" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem>---Select User---</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Patient</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Doctor</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Pharmasits</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Lab Assistance</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlmaritalstatus" runat="server" CssClass="chkbox">
    <asp:ListItem>---Select Status---</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Married</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Unmarried</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

So here i want to handle selected item change event with jquery at ddlusertype, so i used jquery with

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:text').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
    $("select").change(function () {
        alert(this.value);
        if (this.value != "User Select") {
            alert(this.value);
            $('input:text').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('disabled', false);
            });

        }
        if (this.value == "User Select") {
            $('input:text').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Problem is that when again i select "Select User" then event could not be fired up... so please help me out. 
second problem is that i can't differentiate which ddl event occurred  by #IdName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery selector for differentiating purpose to run the dropdown change event separately. Please see:http://jsfiddle.net/2a7fF/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:text').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    });
    $("[id$='ddlusertype']").change(function () {
        alert(this.value);
        //do your work here
    })

   $("[id$='ddlmaritalstatus']").change(function () {
        alert(this.value);
        //do your work here
    })
});
```

For your first problem the jquery script is working fine. Please see jsfiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/mb225/

Comment: value of option could not be changed, i change value like this,
click on masked arrow of ddl and click on edit times, then i change values to 0,1,2 and so on, and then i build my project and refresh webpage and when i see view page source values not changed, please help me

Comment: When you build your project then all dll will recompile and all session and views will destroy. I don't understand exact step to reproduce but normally all controls will missed their last state when you build your project..

Comment: Okay, then how could i change the values for option of ddl, it always default value is its text
For example for ddlusertype value for patient will be always patient, whether i change it to other value.

Comment: Can you please see your console window in firebug or google chrome in inspect element option. May be you will see any error in jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlusertype" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

Change AutoPostBack="False", otherwise the page will reload, and your function won't be called

Comment: Brother, i am newbie in asp.net Thanx for help :D

Comment: Did it fix your problem?

Comment: I don't knw about AutoPostback, and viewstate etc... but issues in jquery i think so...

Comment: If you change AutoPostBack to "False", the event will be fired. If you want to select DropdownList by Id, try adding this ClientIDMode="Static"

Comment: Brother problem solved, but another problem is that when we add option to ddl then at that time default value generated with text for option. so i want to change that default value. but it could not be changed.